# jquery autocomplete script

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a list of cities name. I just want to do, if user type type "a" in the text box, then all the city name which contains "a" will be displayed in drop down box.
Can someone tell me from where I got this type of script. If you have some link then send me.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin.

http://jqueryui.com/home